# Selecting a Screenshot isn't accurate in C# and WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

i made a program for taking a schreenshot from a selected area on the screen but it isn't accurate and i can't figure out why. It's problably because of mouse coordinates but I don't know what I did wrong. Maybe some of you could figure it out. The screenshot is always off and it catches the area of the screen above the actual selection and therefore "cuts" the lower part of the selection . This is my code:

```
     public  partial class Selektiranje : Window
    {
        public double x;
        public double y;
        public double width;
        public double height;
        public bool isMouseDown = false;


        public Selektiranje()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
        {
            isMouseDown = true;
            x = e.GetPosition(null).X;                                                  //Selekcija Screenshota
            y = e.GetPosition(null).Y;
        }

        public  void Window_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.isMouseDown)
            {
                double curx = e.GetPosition(null).X;
                double cury = e.GetPosition(null).Y;

                System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle r = new  , System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
                SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                r.Stroke = brush;
                r.Fill = brush;
                r.StrokeThickness = 1;
                r.Width = Math.Abs(curx - x);
                r.Height = Math.Abs(cury - y);
                selekt.Children.Clear();
                selekt.Children.Add(r);
                Canvas.SetLeft(r, x);
                Canvas.SetTop(r, y);
                if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
                {
                    selekt.Children.Clear();
                    width = e.GetPosition(null).X - x;
                    height = e.GetPosition(null).Y - y;
                    this.CaptureScreen(x, y, width, height);
                    this.x = this.y = 0;
                    this.isMouseDown = false;
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        public void CaptureScreen(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            int ix, iy, iw, ih;
            ix = Convert.ToInt32(x);
            iy = Convert.ToInt32(y);
            iw = Convert.ToInt32(width);
            ih = Convert.ToInt32(height);
            Bitmap slika = new Bitmap(iw, ih,       System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(slika);
            g.CopyFromScreen(ix, iy, 0, 0,new System.Drawing.Size(iw, ih),CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);


 public void SaveScreen(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            int ix, iy, iw, ih;
            ix = Convert.ToInt32(x);
            iy = Convert.ToInt32(y);
            iw = Convert.ToInt32(width);
            ih = Convert.ToInt32(height);
            try
            {
                Bitmap slika = new Bitmap(iw, ih);
                Graphics gr1 = Graphics.FromImage(slika);
                IntPtr dc1 = gr1.GetHdc();
                IntPtr dc2 = NativeMethods.GetWindowDC(NativeMethods.GetForegroundWindow());
                NativeMethods.BitBlt(dc1, ix, iy, iw, ih, dc2, ix, iy, 13369376);
                gr1.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
                System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
                dlg.DefaultExt = "png";
                dlg.Filter = "Png Files|*.png";
                DialogResult res = dlg.ShowDialog();
                if (res == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    slika.Save(dlg.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);

            }
            catch 
            {

            }

        }
        internal class NativeMethods
        {

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public extern static IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hwnd);
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern UInt64 BitBlt(IntPtr hDestDC, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hSrcDC, int xSrc, int ySrc, System.Int32 dwRop);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics.CopyFromScreen` needs the screen coordinates to take picture. You are passing coorduinates relative to form because of using e.x and e.y of `MouseEventArgs`. You should use screen coordinates of mouse instead, using  `Cursor.Position` or `MousePosition` that are identical.

**If you are using WPF**

There are many options that may help you to get screen coordinates, some of those options:

**Option 1**

You can use [PointToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen.aspx) method to convert the coordinates to screen coordinates.

**Option 2**

In WPF you cant use those methods, the most simple way would be add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` to your WPF project and then use `System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition` which is static.

**Option 3**

As another option you can add a reference to `System.Drawing.dll` and use this:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref PointStruct point);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct PointStruct
{
    public Int32 X;
    public Int32 Y;
};

public static System.Drawing.Point MousePosition()
{
    var mousePosition = new PointStruct();
    GetCursorPos(ref mousePosition);
    return new System.Drawing.Point(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y);
}
```

Then you can use `MousePosition()` to get the current position of mouse on screen.

Comment: Thanks but as I said my program doesn't recognize .Position property, probably because I mixed WPF and WinForms together.

Comment: @drake not so big problem. Do you want to capture only region of form? or all of screen? this way when you can't capture outside of form.

Comment: I want to capture whatever region I want from screen, it could be desktop, a program anything. It doesn't have to be a region of form

Comment: @drake But the solution you are using only can capture regions of form

Comment: No i can capture anything I want, the problem is that is not accurate

Comment: @drake How does `Window_MouseDown` act if you click outside of window?

Comment: It works fine, I'm not clicking on the window anyway because i made it very small. I can select anything from anywhere I want

Comment: yeah I have this problem also that I have to select (move my mouse) from top to bottom. If I select the other way from bottom to top the program crashes

Comment: I'm already using a reference to System.Windows.Forms and it doesn't recognize .MousePosition

Comment: @drake `System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition`

Comment: @drake check the last option :) all options work here, probably there is a problem with your project - check edited answer

Comment: @drake did you test the latest option?

Comment: yeah they work but they are even more inaccurate. The selection doesn't start at the point where I put the mouse down. I just realized that in my method the selection works great and that wasn't ever the problem but the problem is that the screenshot is not the same as the selection: In the selection the mouse pointer is precise and selection is highlighted as it supposed to be it's just that the screenshot (image) comes out wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Cursor.Position (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx)  in `Window_MouseDown()` and `Window_MouseMove()` which returns absolute mouse coordinates.

```
   private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    {
        isMouseDown = true;
        x = Cursor.Position.X;
        y = Cursor.Position.Y;
    }
```

Code of a fully working solution (for me) below. I removed unnecessary code such as drawing the rectangle. In addition, I hide the form before taking the screenshot. You could also set the form's background color to a specific value and set the transparency key to the same value or something.

But the basic concept remains: use absolute screen coordinates.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Media;
using PixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat;
using Rectangle = System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public double x;
        public double y;
        public double width;
        public double height;
        public bool isMouseDown;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SaveScreen(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            var ix = Convert.ToInt32(x);
            var iy = Convert.ToInt32(y);
            var iw = Convert.ToInt32(width);
            var ih = Convert.ToInt32(height);
            try
            {
                var slika = new Bitmap(iw, ih, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                var g = Graphics.FromImage(slika);
                g.CopyFromScreen(ix, iy, 0, 0, new Size(iw, ih), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                var dlg = new SaveFileDialog
                {
                    DefaultExt = "png",
                    Filter = "Png Files|*.png"
                };
                var res = dlg.ShowDialog();
                if (res == DialogResult.OK) slika.Save(dlg.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isMouseDown = true;
            x = Cursor.Position.X;
            y = Cursor.Position.Y;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            width = Cursor.Position.X - x;
            height = Cursor.Position.Y - y;
            Hide();
            Size = new Size(0, 0);
            Application.DoEvents();
            SaveScreen(x, y, width, height);
            x = y = 0;
            isMouseDown = false;
            Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and I am using System.Windows.Forms; in my program but it says it doesn't recognize Position property

Comment: Somehow you're mixing WPF and Winforms in a way I could not make it compile yet.

Comment: Yeah  I was supposed to do it only with WPF but I didn't find adequate solutions for that so now it's all mixed up and I don't know how much time would it take to rewrite it all in WPF (and if I'm able to do that). It compiles fine and works except that the screenshot is not accurate. But still I don't know why it wont recognize Position if I'm using System.Windows.Forms

Comment: @drake are you passing screen coordinates (not coordinate relative to form)? In code you posted here, you are passing coordinates using e.x and e.y that is relative to forms

Comment: @drake: I pasted a fully working solution. Note that I reduced the code even more. I got rid of drawing the rectangle etc.

Comment: @Thomas Weller thank you very much for you help but it doesn' work in my case. It's probably because I used WPF and Win Forms together and there's some kind of a conflict. Because my MainWindow is in WPF. I should probably have to rewrite it all using just WPF as I was supposed to do. The only problem is that I'm not so experienced with it and my deadline is tomorrow :)  I'll probably leave it this way because I have a couple more things I have to do and I don't know how.